# How to implement Row Level Security for anonymous orders

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I'm designing a database for a commercial website. Here's a table to store user's order:

```
create table orders(
  id uuid primary key default uuid_generate_v4(),
  client_name text references public.address(client_name),
  payment_method smallint not null,
  order_state text not null default 'pending'::text,
  note text,
  is_verified boolean not null default false,
  created_at timestamp not null default now(),
  modified_at timestamp not null default now(),
  canceled_at timestamp
)
```

and the address table:

```
create table address(
  id serial primary key,
  user_id uuid references public.user(id),
  client_name text not null,
  note text,
  address text not null,
  phone text not null,
  email text
  created_at timestamp not null default now(),
  modified_at timestamp not null default now(),
  canceled_at timestamp
)
```

The idea is that if an authenticated user places an order, i will insert in the order table, as each user already have at least 1 shipping address. If an anonymous user place an order, i will first insert a new address, then insert the order. Note that column reference `user_id` could be `null`.

Now to the RLS part. Implementing RLS for authenticated user is not hard, since i can use `user_id`. The problem is with anonymous user, I can't think of any good ideas.

I can disable delete, update and select, but for the insert, i can't think of anything to prevent spamming fake orders.

Any solution for this? I have search for hours but didn't find any useful information.

Comment: How do you distinguish a fake order from a real order? And what does this have to do with the database RLS?